# from selenium import webdriver ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' (PyCharm)

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I have a trouble in PyCharm during running my script with Selenium WebDriver:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/ratmir/PycharmProjects/TestAutomationGF/Test/firsttest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ratmir/PycharmProjects/TestAutomationGF/Test/firsttest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

I have checked that selenium was installed:

```
python -m pip install -U selenium
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

I see that in PyCharm I have another version of Python... Could you please help me to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `python -m pip install selenium` in Python27 folder or Python34 folder whichever you use (preferably 3.4) and then try in PyCharm by selecting the corresponding interpreter in settings or else use PyCharm to do the installation.