# Python can not find Selenium module

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is not a duplicate as I used the previous solutions but did not solve the problem.

I need to install Selenium in python. I used this command as suggested in [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734903/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-selenium-message):

```
python -m pip install -U selenium
```

This is the output I get:

```
Collecting selenium
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (904kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 911kB 1.5MB/s 
Collecting urllib3 (from selenium)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/00/ee1d7de624db8ba7090d1226aebefab96a2c71cd5cfa7629d6ad3f61b79e/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: urllib3, selenium
Successfully installed selenium-3.141.0 urllib3-1.24.1
```

I then try to run a python code:

```
python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
>>>
```

Comment: propably you have few versions of python installed, try to use
`python3 -m pip install -U selenium`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be the fact that you are installing it into python2 by running `python -m pip install -U selenium`. Some devices such as Macs use python2 and in order to run python3 commands you can either add an alias `alias python=python3` in your .bashrc or .zshrc file or you can run them with the prefix `python3`.

**Try running `python3 -m pip install -U selenium`.**

If this gives you access denied run it with sudo: `sudo -H python3 -m pip install -U selenium`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

**You have to check if you use same pip that is provided alongside your python.** To check it, use `which`.

```
$ which python3                                                                                                                                                                      
>> /usr/local/bin/python3
$ which pip3                                                                                                                                                                         
>> /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

If they are on same location you can use:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have a different version of Python(possible 2.7.x) installed on the the same computer. In such a case, you need to change directory to the Scripts folder of the python version you want it installed. Kindly reply, for more instructions.

Answer (score 0):

"python3 -m pip install -U selenium" fixed the problem for me.
Thanks.